# Power BI - This content isn't available. Learn more about Power BI

Tags: permissions, access, powerbi

I have replaced a colleague who has left the company 1 month before my arrival. 
Hence he could not give all permissions directly to me but the management and the support team has to deal with it. 
Unfortunately there are some issues with that.

I have been informed that I've received all required permissions but I still get an error message (see below).

[image]

My ex-colleague won't be able to help, support says it should be the manager to help me out with that, but my manager is not an IT person so she is not really able to go further with that. So I'm stuck now.

Comment: I'm quite sure I should be able to see the file under "shared with me" section in Power BI App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, you need to have "Power BI Pro Licence" to be able to view the report with this web part.

Please also consider, adding the report in SharePoint page/teamsite does not automatically grant access to the report for the users the page is shared with. Users should be added as members of app workspace in Power BI service.

Besides not having access to the report, another common reason for getting this message is that the report was deleted.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. 
I have now Pro Licence and I can see the report file. 
Thank you for this.